# Is it possible to lose HP on gaining a level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-levels, hit-points

Say I have a Con modifier of -2 and I roll a 1 for HP on level up, does my max HP go down by 1?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**No**

> You apply your character's Constitution modifier to:
>
> - Each roll of a Hit Die (though a penalty can never drop a result below 1—that is, a character always gains at least 1 hit point each time he advances in level).
> - Fortitude saving throws, for resisting poison, disease, and similar threats.

-[d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores)

So you get a -2 to the roll, but the total can't go below 1.